# find files starting with some string in several directories

Tags: command-line, bash

I have file with a list of names like (names.txt):

```
A
B 
C
```

And directories and file path like:

```
sess/N0/A.dgdg
sess/N1/X.dhhj
sess/N2/B.gggj
sess/N3/K.jkjj
sess/N4/C.9293
```

And I need to print those directories that contain files starting with A, B, or C.So, the desired output is:

```
sess/N0/A.dgdg
sess/N2/B.gggj
sess/N4/C.9293
```

or better:

```
N0
N2
N4
```

I tried the following bash script being executed in "sess" directory:

```
cat names.txt | while read line
do
 find . -name \$line* -type f >> output 
done
```

I know that the command itself is fine, but it does not work in an loop.

Comment: The output and the files names are a list. Don't know why it looks horrible in the post.

Comment: You want `$line` to be expanded by the shell, but `*` not; `\$line*` does the opposite. Try `"$line*"`

Comment: Thank you!! it is working!!! Thanks for the explanation. Best regards